# Vertical-align with Pure CSS (from YUI)

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

How can I add `vertical-align: middle` to elements using **[PureCSS, from YUI](http://purecss.io/)**?

I have three elements with have the same height, and I want that, "inside", they have `vertical-align: middle`.

=> **Check jsfiddle: *http://jsfiddle.net/kn88b/1/***

The closest I get was with `display: table; width: 100%`, but this BUGs the "mobile version", so I want a solution for all versions (tablet/desktop/mobile).

[image]

Comment: How about using media queries to set them to `display: table` just on the bigger devices?

Comment: @davidpauljunior This was my first thought when I reached no solution. Ask in Stackoverflow was the second (and here I am. haha)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use flexboxes! Here is a JSFiddle that I've tested in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/kn88b/6/

I specified `display: flex` on `.a,.b,.c` and specified `margin: auto` on `.inside`

To make this cross browser, just make sure you use all the vendor prefixes.

You can learn more about flexboxes here:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

Comment: What about browser compatability ??

Comment: Thank you, Eli. Browser compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/flexbox – Will not be compatible with *non-actual* browsers, but -until now- is the best answer, since works with just CSS and do not use `media queries` (my second way out).

Comment: What do you mean by "non-actual" browsers? Flexbox support is pretty wide reaching once you use the appropriate prefixes and such.

Comment: You are right, I don't know where I saw that. Sorry and thank you for yout answer. :-)

Comment: Actual in spanish is the equivalent of modern in english. For those who might be confused by this statement.

Comment: This technique is broken in Firefox, and it doesn't really center in IE.
I managed to fix the fact that it breaks in FF on every element by saying `display: inline-flex`, but centering still broken. Any idea how to get this working in browsers other than Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kn88b/3/ . Used `display:table` for parent element, and `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` for children content

Comment: Look at the 'mobile version' (resize jsfiddle preview window to a smaller size). This is the bug I said, `.a` gets a bigger size than `.b` and `.c`. (image: http://i.imgur.com/wHfmAzP.png)